# Parse XML and Create DIV's JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm looking for a way to parse an XML document and then create corresponding DIV's in an HTML page based on the document.  After a brief google search I haven't found of an out of the box way of doing this.  I was wondering if anyone knows of a relatively simple way to achieve this?  For example take the following XML sample

```
<parent>
  <node1>Some Value1</node1>
  <node2>Some Value2</node2>
  <node3>
    <childNode1>Some Child Value1</childNode1>
    <childNode2>Some Child Value2</childNode2>
  </node3>
</parent>
```

I would want to parse this and generate the following

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="node1">Some Value1</div>
  <div id="node2">Some Value2</div>

  <div id="node3">
    <div id="childNode1">Some Child Value1</div>
    <div id="childNode2">Some Child Value2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sure doesn't seem like you looked very hard in your search ...lots of results here https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+parse+xml

Comment: Does this need to be done with jQuery/JavaScript? Have you looked into making an XSLT? http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
var xmlString = '<parent>\
  <node1>Some Value1</node1>\
  <node2>Some Value2</node2>\
  <node3>\
    <childNode1>Some Child Value1</childNode1>\
    <childNode2>Some Child Value2</childNode2>\
  </node3>\
</parent>'

$(document).ready(function() {
    var xml = $.parseXML(xmlString);

    xml2html($(':root', xml), $('body'));
});

function xml2html(xml, container) {
    var tagName = $(xml).get(0).tagName;
    var div = $(document.createElement('div'))
                    .attr({ id: tagName })
                    .appendTo(container)

    if($(xml).children().length == 0) {
        div.text($(xml).text());
    }
    else {
        $(xml).children().each(function(index, node) {
            xml2html(node, div);
        });
    }
}
```

see Fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/oezm5u4x/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the jQuery api.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

I would start with an empty div element (with an id) to start, that way you can insert your new html into that spot.

```
    <div id="parent"></div>
```

Another option is to load the entire xml into javascript as a string and parse it out manually.  it is messy but doable given the clean/uniform formatting in XML.